# Combining the first 25 elements from a data frame's column with an empty vector using the while loop

Tags: r, if-statement, indexing, while-loop

I made the following code:

```
NovelID <- NULL

x <- 1

while(x < 25) {
  if(length(NovelID) < 25) {
    NovelID <- c(NovelID, SalesList$BookID[SalesList$BookType[] == "Novel"])
    x <- x + 1
  }
}
```

So, I have a dataset named SalesList, which has multiple columns, but I am only interested in those named BookType and BookID. The BookType column has multiple types of book (ScienceFiction, Religion, Novel, etc...) and each of these books have a corresponding book id in the BookID column. I wanted to have the book ids of the first 25 books which have the type "novel" entered into the newly formed vector named NovelID. When I ran the code (provided above), the code kept on running, so I had to force stop it. After that, I checked the length of NovelID and its length was equal to the number of books in the dataset with the type "novel" (which is 121). I couldn't make the loop work one by one, as it would get stuck after entering the loop for the second time because now the length of NovelID had become 121 (thus exceeding the limit of 25). As far as I am concerned, my mistake lies in the part of the code where I am trying to combine NovelID with the data, more specifically, in the indexing part. However, I am unsure of what code to enter to get the result I want, using the while loop. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Loop is not needed. Simply run your boolean logic with numbered index: `NovelID <- SalesList$BookID[SalesList$BookType == "Novel"][1:25]` or with `head`: `NovelID <- head(SalesList$BookID[SalesList$BookType == "Novel"], 25)`. Typically in R you want to aim for vectorized, non-loop operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, in R this approach of growing vectors in a loop is not recommended. See Circle 2: Growing Object of Patrick Burns' [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Additionally, R has many compact statements like the *apply* family to avoid bookkeeping where you initialize an empty object and expand it. Also, R tends to be more functional and object-oriented in its paradigm. If possible run whole processes on an object such as vectorized operations and avoid state/instance based data processing.

Specifically, your immediate issue is that with each loop iteration you continue to append ***all*** Novel `BookID`s to the `NovelID` vector and not condition it one by one which with iterator `x`.

**Growing Object in Loop**

```r
NovelID <- NULL

x <- 1

while(x <= 25) {
  if(length(NovelID) <= 25) {
    NovelID <- c(NovelID, SalesList$BookID[SalesList$BookType == "Novel"][x])
    x <- x + 1
  }  
}
```

**Using Pre-Defined Length**

But better to initialize your object with a length and assign values by index.

```r
NovelID <- vector(mode="integer", length=25)

x <- 1

while(x <= 25) {
  if(length(NovelID) <= 25) {
    NovelID[x] <- SalesList$BookID[SalesList$BookType == "Novel"][x]
  }
  x <- x + 1
}
```

**Apply Family**

Even better avoid any bookkeeping of initialized object and repetitive assignment.

```r
# VECTOR OUTPUT IF YOU DO NOT KNOW OUTPUT TYPE
NovelID <- sapply(1:25, function(x) SalesList$BookID[SalesList$BookType == "Novel"][x])

# VECTOR OUTPUT IF YOU DO KNOW OUTPUT TYPE
NovelID <- vapply(1:25, function(x) SalesList$BookID[SalesList$BookType == "Novel"][x], integer(1))
```

---

However, you want to avoid any loop (hidden or not) with vectorized operations

```r
NovelID <- SalesList$BookID[SalesList$BookType == "Novel"][1:25]

NovelID <- head(SalesList$BookID[SalesList$BookType == "Novel"], 25)
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/VKK44680)</kbd>